# Dynamic height label and Text field

Tags: ios, autolayout

In the picture below they have these constraints:
[image]

I am confused how constraints 4-7 work. This recipe claims that it dynamically sets the vertical spacing of the controls (name label and name text view) based on the tallest control (height wise) at runtime. So if the label has an intrinsic height of 48 (due to increased font) somehow the textview's height will also match the name label's height. I don't see that relationship anywhere in code something like: `nameTextView.height = nameLabel.height + 0`?

Also in constraint 4 it's saying it couldbe >= but in constraint 5 it's saying it has to be equal to (with a lower priority). How does the system decide which constraint to use at what time?

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ViewswithIntrinsicContentSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH13-SW16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraints 5 and 7 are there to define default values for the interface as constraints 4 and 6 are inequalities and accepts more than one possibility.

In this example they never say that `nameTextView` and `nameLabel` would be necessarily the same height. These four constraints are actually taking care of their different heights.

So here is how they work:

Constraints 4 and 6 define that the distance from top to `nameLabel` and `nameTextView`, respectively, CAN BE (attention on this term) equal or greater than 20. So if you set only these two, Xcode will be lost if they are actually greater or equal, that's why you need to have the low priority constraints (5 and 7), they give the guideline to Xcode that in low priority they'll both "start" at 20, then the program tries to satisfy 4 and 6, by checking who's taller (because 4 and 6 admits 20 or GREATER): `nameLabel` or `nameTextView`. If `nameLabel` is taller, constraint 4 is satisfied by setting its vertical distance to 20 and constraint 6 will be satisfied by setting `nameTextView` vertical distance to the top as GREATER than 20 (automatically calculated by the difference of their height). Now, with everything satisfied, autolayout will succeed!

Hope this helps.

Comment: So the system will first try to fulfill constraints 5 and 7 even though they have a lower priority than 4 and 6?

Comment: Actually I think first it will see 4 and 6, as they have higher priority, but as they are inequalities, they will see the low priority constraint and then understand what to do, as afore mentioned

Comment: "If nameLabel is taller, constraint 4 is satisfied by setting its vertical distance to 20 and constraint 6 will be satisfied by setting nameTextView vertical distance to the top as GREATER than 20 (automatically calculated by the difference of their height)" If the name label is taller why is the vertical distance 20 but the constraint 6 will be greater than 20? Maybe I am not understanding what this inequality actually means. The constraint is acting like a boolean in some way and simply checking if it is greater than or equal to 20 and not actually setting a value for the constraint?

Comment: The inequality sets two acceptable cases for the constraint: either the vertical spacing can be 20 or it can be greater. It's definitely a different type of constraint. It alone can't set the vertical spacing, that's why you need the low priority one. In the sentence you quoted: if one is taller than another, the "greater than" part of the constraint calculates the spacing being bigger than 20 whereas in the other view, the "equals to" part sets it to 20.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Based on the sentence quoted why can't both be `>=20` since constraints 4 and 6 specify BOTH have to be `>=20` correct? So if name label is taller then it will be greater than or equal to 20 and the name text field somehow gets defaulted to only being 20 despite constraint 6 which is saying `>=20`?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm getting what you are saying. Both ARE `>=20` in all the cases. `=20` IS `>=20`, it's one of the particular cases of `>=20`. The important parts is that you can't remove the low priority constraints because the program needs a starting value. Otherwise it can't decide which will be the spacing (as `>=20` contains an infinite set of values). So, the tallest view in this case will always default to `=20` and the shortest will be `20+theHeightDifference` which is greater than 20.

Comment: Sorry for asking again but I am particularly confused here: "So the tallest view in this case will always default to =20 and the shortest will be 20+theHeightDifference which is greater than 20." Why does the tallest view always default to `=20` and where is this `theHeightDifference` coming from? I think I am missing something obvious here sorry.

Comment: If you look at constraint number 8, it says that the baseline of both texts should be equal. If you have different sizes on the label and the textview, you can't have the same top space in both views (i.e. 20).
So what happens is, they start at 20, it tries to satisfy the baseline constraint, fails and changes the top space in the shortest to be greater than 20. If it did this to the tallest, you wouldn't be able to match the baselines as you would need a smaller than 20 constant to satisfy this situation. So there you go, it sets the tallest to `=20` and the shortest to `>20`.